# Should we test error terms for auto correlation or multicollinearity

Tags: regression, autocorrelation, multicollinearity

I understand the basic difference in definition between multicollinearity and autocorrelation. I.e multicollinearity describes a linear relationship between whereas autocorrelation describes correlation of a variable with itself given a time lag.

When should I test for these as part of hypotheses testing?  When fitting a model to a time series are the error terms tested for autocorrelation or multicollinearity?  Why one over the other?

In a linear regression between Y and X with no time component, I suppose the answer is easy? We fit a linear model and test the residuals for multicollinearity and not autocorrelation because we are not considering time as a factor here.  I am sorry for such a naive question.

Comment: There was a question with almost exactly the same title. Did you search SE?

Comment: How does one "test residuals for multicollinearity"? What specifically do you mean by "multicollinearity" of a set of *residuals* (which is just a collection of numbers)?

Comment: It's an interesting question: when do residuals become collinear? When two variables are impacted by exactly the same shock. For instance, $y_t=t+\varepsilon$ and $z_t=t^2+\varepsilon$, teh same errors.

Comment: @Aksakal: Collinearity is a relationship among *vectors*, not a property of a set of numbers. So what specifically do you mean by "residuals become collinear"?  Collinear *with what*?

Comment: @whuber, I was thinking that he might be running a regression on vector of dependent variables, and got a residuals for all variables, and was wondering if they're multicollinear.

Comment: @Aksakal That's a plausible interpretation. We need to seek clarification from Victor, who has to this point not indicated whether the time series is a multivariate one.  Even the [tag:multivariate] tag, which is usually applied to such problems, has not been used here.

Comment: No it is not a multivariate time series.

Comment: Ok, then exactly what do you mean by "multicollinearity"?  It appears you have made an effort to characterize it in your first paragraph, but something got garbled or lost between "between" and "whereas".

Comment: @Victor, if it's univariate series, then mutlicollinearity is not even applicable here to residuals. It's for vectors, particularly, explanatory variable vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multicollinearity can't even be defined unless you have multiple explanatory ("X") variables.

Your explanation doesn't suggest you fully understand these two terms.  After all, correlation expresses collinearity.  Auto-correlation merely means that you will find significant collinearity if you regress the dependent variable against itself with some lag.

Also, before you just start running tests you should assert a model (and hypothesis).  I.e., ask yourself whether it is even reasonable to suggest that one explanatory variable is correlated with another, or that the predicted variable have some time interdependence with its own value.